# Handle a webpage in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#

Is any way to handle a webpage (ex. Google.com) elements like changing a textBox content or click on some button with JavaScript?

I already do this with `WebBrowser` in C#:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Url = new Uri("https://google.com");
wb.Document.GetElementById("lst-ib").InnerText = "Stackoverflow";
wb.Document.GetElementById("btnK").InvokeMember("Click");
```

This code changes Google.com Search field to "Stackoverflow" and then clicks on "Google Search" button.

Comment: what do you mean 'handle'? give an example

Comment: maybe phantomjs or nwjs will allow you to "automate" website interaction

Comment: can you clarify a bit about handling? if you mean headless browser, phantom js will help you.